# Can we always find an invertible matrix from a non-invertible one

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I was trying to prove that, For $n\times n$ matrices $P$ and $Q$, $PQ$ and $QP$ have same *eigenvalue*(not given $Q$ is invertible or not). My approach is as follows:We have $Q(PQ)Q^{-1}=QP$, from this we can directly see that they have same eigenvalue *if* $Q$ is invertible. Now, as changing position of entries doesn't change the eigenvalues, hence, I have an idea to prove the rest of the problem.

> Can we always find invertible matrix by changing the positions of
>   entries of a non-invertible matrix?

If the above statement is true then we can always get an matrix after rearranging the entries which is non-invertible and has same eigenvalues as the privious non-invertible matrix had and as the reduced matrix(after rearranging entries) $Q'$ satisfy:$$Q'(PQ')Q'^{-1}=Q'P$$hence, eigenvalues of $PQ'$ and $Q'P$ are same which is also equal to eigenvalue of $PQ$.

Now, my question is , is the quoted statement is true?

Comment: No, if there are fewer than $n$ non-zero entries in $Q$ then no rearrangement will give something invertible.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Can you explain it little bit, or give a link. thank you

Comment: There is not much to explain. If you are studying eigenvalues, then the statement I wrote should be very straight forward to show (consider the determinant).